# In a while loop, fgets() runs by its self taking in a newline as the input

Tags: c, while-loop, fgets, strtol

```
char theInput[10];
long option;
int innerLoop = 1;
char *dunno;
while(innerLoop == 1){
  printf("\nType '1' to get your change, '2' to select another item, or '3' to add more funds: ");
  fgets(theInput, sizeof theInput, stdin);
  option = strtol(theInput, &dunno, 10);
  if(option == 1){
    loop = 0;
    innerLoop = 0;
  }else if(option == 2){
    loop = 1;
    outerLoop = 1;
    innerLoop = 0;
    firstLoop = 0;
  }else if(option == 3){
    loop = 1;
    innerLoop = 0;
    outerLoop = 1;
    firstLoop = 1;
  }else{
    printf("\nInvalid input, please try again.\n");
    innerLoop = 1;
  }
}
```

The result of this code is that when first ran, it prints the "Type '1' to get" part followed by a line break followed by "Invalid input, please try again." without taking any input from the command line. It then prints the first printf statement again, and then accepts an input and works. It is meant to print the first statement then wait for an input.

Below is the terminal output.

"Type '1' to get your change, '2' to select another item, or '3' to add more funds: 
Invalid input, please try again.

Type '1' to get your change, '2' to select another item, or '3' to add more funds: "

Comment: The code you have posted does not print the stuff you mention (e.g. the "Type 'C' to get your change," part). It's probable that the error is in the part of your code that you did not post..

Comment: Thanks for your response. That is my mistake of updating my code whilst posting - I changed it from C, N and A to 1, 2, 3 because I thought processing integers might be easier. I have updated the post so everything is as it currently runs on my computer.

Comment: Earlier unposted code used an input function that left a `'\n'` in `stdin`.

Comment: It works on my machine, so I guess someone edited your post and accidentally fixed the bug you had problems with?

Comment: I suspect there's a `scanf` that's called before this code runs. Which is why debugging questions should always contain a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try to flush the stdout?

I 've added the main method if other people would like to have a working example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
  int loop = 0;
  int outerLoop = 0;
  int firstLoop = 0;

  char theInput[10];
  long option;
  int innerLoop = 1;
  char *dunno;
  while(innerLoop == 1){
    printf("\nType '1' to get your change, '2' to select another item, or '3' to add more funds: ");
    fflush(stdout);
    fgets(theInput, sizeof theInput, stdin);
    option = strtol(theInput, &dunno, 10);
    if(option == 1) {
      loop = 0;
      innerLoop = 0;
    }else if(option == 2){
      loop = 1;
      outerLoop = 1;
      innerLoop = 0;
      firstLoop = 0;
    }else if(option == 3){
      loop = 1;
      innerLoop = 0;
      outerLoop = 1;
      firstLoop = 1;
    }else{
      printf("\nInvalid input, please try again.\n");
      innerLoop = 1;
    }
  }
}
```

Before adapting your source code, can you try running this example in isoltion and to see if you have the expected results?